# How to create array list from for loop in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio, arraylist

I am working on a project in VS built with react (I'm new to react) and I have a loop function that returns json data and I am trying to create a list/array - `[1, 2, 3, 4]` using the IDs from the loop -

```
for (const data of data.dataset) {
    ID = data.id;
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let myArray = [];

for (let data of data.dataset) {
    myArray.push(data.id)
}

console.log(myArray); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

You can use this method to create a new array with ID's.